# I want to detect when a model is closed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want my form to be reset when my modal is closed.
Well modal can be closed by clicking the close button or by clicking else where in the page.
My modal is as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="uploadVideo">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <form>
    <!-- form contents-->
    </form>

    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="upload_video_close" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                <button type="submit" id="upload-video-button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </div>

</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

Now what i am doing is i trigger form reset on click of that close button.

```
$(document).on('click', '#upload_video_close', function () {
    $('form').trigger("reset");
});
```

This piece of code here is doing just fine when i close the modal by clicking on close button.
But i want the form to be reset upon the modal close not only by closing it on click of close button but also by clicking else where on web page too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

})
```

Check [These](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) for more information. You need to use Events.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`.hidden.bs.modal event`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)** as below:

```
$("#uploadVideo").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
    //reset your form
    //this will fire whenever the modal is closed by any sort of actions
});
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    //your button
    var closeButton = $("#upload_video_close");

    //your modal
    var container = $(".modal");

    //if you clicked outside of modal or on the button
    if ((!container.is(e.target)
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) || closeButton.is(e.target))
    {
        $('form').trigger("reset");
    }
});
```